# When adding video in raw folder shows error in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am new to the android studio, when I add a video in the raw folder it shows an error like "file was loaded in wrong encoding utf-8. I don't know how to remove this error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It must be in a supported format (3gp, wmv, mp4 ).